# How are the powers being changed

Tags: abstract-algebra, semigroups, magma

I have a semigroup $S$ including a generator, say $d$, such that $$d^4=d$$ I am trying to guess the general rule of $d$'s powers such that when I want to calculate $d^n, n\in\mathbb N$; I can simplify it to a reduced possible power(s).

---

Obviously, I have: $$(*)~~d=d^4=d^7=d^{10}=d^{13}=...\\(**)~~d^2=d^5=d^8=d^{11}=d^{14}=...\\(***)~~d^3=d^6=d^9=d^{12}=d^{15}=...$$ and checking the powers with [OEIS](http://oeis.org/) was useless to give me any proper rules for each cases above. For example, what is $d^{33}$? I just could write it as the following to find out that; it is $d^3$: $$d^{33}=d\cdot d^{32}=d\cdot(d^4)^8=d\cdot(d^4)^2=d\cdot d^2=d^3$$

Can we say:

The OEIS couldn't find any matchable sequences to rule the powers, so my question does not make any senses.

Thanks for your time and your any help.

Comment: I'm curious to know, what did you actually type into OEIS?  It certainly finds the three arithmetic sequences you've listed above!

Comment: @TaraB: In fact, I found those by hands, and just wanted to know what is the general rule of changing  the powers.

Comment: I'm just puzzled by the parts in your question where you talk about OEIS.  Actually, I hope you don't mind me saying this, but I'm actually puzzled that you asked this question at all.  It surprises me that you got as far as typing up the whole thing without noticing what the answer was.  (I'm not trying to say "you're stupid", I'm trying to say "my impression, from your other activity on the site, was that you would have easily been able to answer this question if it had been asked by someone else".)

Comment: I agree with Tara. Besides, look at http://oeis.org/A016777

Comment: @TaraB: First of all, thank you for your consideration to this question. You know, sometimes, I feel to ask something here at the site, and honestly this time is the second one. However, the problem be so easy to be solved. In fact, I knew the relation which you and Andre kindly noted me. :-)

Comment: @TaraB: I remember, at the first time I got -1 just for asking a question and DonAntoino complained the one who did it. I don't want to examine my knowledge here because it seems so ugly. But, I want to share something different here and I 've found out that semigroups is one of them. I couldn't find many about this area here.

Comment: @TaraB: Any way, sometimes the point in a question is so clear that you cannot see it clearly. You cannot see the Sun directly. Thanks again and I hope I didn't say any things bad. If I did, I do apologize you highly. :-)

Comment: @BabakS.: Please don't be put off asking future questions on semigroups by my comment.  It's one of the tags I pay most attention to, so I would quite like there to be more questions on it!

Comment: @TaraB: I think I think your comments are/were off-putting. They are certainly not helpful nor constructive. Your comments are the sorts of comments that *discourage* questions being asked: questions by knowledgeable users, or otherwise. It's comments like yours that keep ME from posting questions, lest they appear "stupid" or motivate users like you from responding in a manner which, more or less, says "You should *know* that? Shame on you for asking!"

Comment: Let's all please try to keep comments as encouraging and *welcoming* as possible? Sarcasm and "shaming" sorts of comments can be very hurtful to some questioners. Let's always keep in mind that factors like gender, culture, and just sheer variations in the sensitivity of sincere souls seeking deeper understanding, in the forefront of our minds when responding to posts.  Please consider deleting the offending comments as irrelevant and unhelpful?

Comment: @BabakS.:  Given amWhy's comments, could you please confirm for me whether you were at all offended by my comments?  My impression so far was that you were not, which I was relieved about, because I had been unsure whether I should say anything, and I did try to make it very clear that I wasn't trying to 'shame' you.  But if I did in fact offend you, that would be good for me to know.

Comment: @amWhy:  Do you find any sarcasm or 'shaming' in what I said?  I would not have written those comments to just anyone.  I have had enough interaction with Babak that I felt I could judge accurately that my comment would not be taken amiss.  I am very sorry if I was wrong.

Comment: @TaraB: I want you to put down this conversations by letting you that I have found at last two **finite** Quasi-commutative semigroup(**s**). And I will inform you when they be published. :-)

Comment: @amWhy:  The reason I bothered saying anything at all was because I was sincerely curious about the thought processes going on here.  We all fail to see really obvious things sometimes, and I wanted to know in what direction Babak had been thinking, since I wasn't sure what exactly the business with OEIS was about, as it does find what I would consider the 'obvious' sequences.

Comment: @BabakS.: Great!  However, that doesn't answer my question about whether you were offended (or hurt, or made to feel ashamed).  I really do want to know, so please be honest.  It will help me to improve the way I participate in this site.

Comment: @TaraB: Honestly, My english is not so good as you or amWhy wrote here. I really felt ashamed here yesterday and I wanted to quite the site. I have tryied to treat others as it should be with highly respect I know. But, yesterday, the comments made me tears. Now, I accept that, I shouldn't be so sensitive, and sometimes I cannot get the comments properly. That's why I apologized you. I thought, I did something wrong here and I don't want to be like an offensive person on this great site.

Comment: @BabakS.:  Thank you so much for your honest reply!  It's extremely good for me to know that, so that I can hopefully avoid upsetting anyone else similarly in future.  I am deeply sorry.  You did nothing wrong at all.  I was a little confused by _you_ apologising to _me_, when if anything it did seem it should be the other way around (though I didn't realise I had actually upset you at that point).

Comment: @TaraB, could you please email me, as I indicated in Chat (but some four hours after you left it).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $m\equiv n\pmod{3}$, then $d^m=d^n$. Or, in terms of remainders, $d^n=d^k$, where $k-1$ is the remainder when $n-1$ is divided by $3$.

Answer (score 3):

$d$ generates in $S$ a subgroup with the unity $d^3$. So $d^n=d^{n\pmod{3}}$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, prof. Boris. I am studying the algebraic theory of semigroups vol I by Clifford. May I ask you to inform me additional references as the latter book. Thanks

Comment: @Babak S. It depends on your aim. E.g., if you are close to Computer Sciences then I advise G.Lallement, Semigroups and combinatorial applications. For "pure" Semigroup Theory it would be good J.Howie, An introduction to semigroup theory. Applications to Theory of Rings are in M.Petrich, Rings and semigroups, etc.

Comment: @ Babak S.: Please ask. I don' know how to use chat too :-) Or you can e-mail to me.

Comment: No, I don't know. I think, it is not a standard termin. Where do you see it?

Comment: I sent you an email. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'll just write something about the general case.  An element $d$ of a semigroup is said to have finite order if $d^i = d^{i+k}$ for some $i,k\in \mathbb{N}$.  In groups this reduces to $d^k=1$ and then, if $k$ is minimal, the distinct powers of $d$ are $1,d,\ldots,d^{k-1}$ and for any $m\in \mathbb{N}$ we have $d^m = d^r$, where $r$ is the remainder upon dividing $m$ by $k$.  (You already know this I'm sure.)

In semigroups, the minimal such $i$ and $k$ are called the *index* and *period* respectively.  If $i$ and $k$ are minimal, then the distinct powers of $d$ are $d,\ldots,d^{i+k-1}$.  Note that the powers $d,\ldots,d^{i-1}$ 'never occur again' (that is, no higher powers are equal to them).  The elements $d^i,\ldots,d^{i+k-1}$ form a group (exercise: find the identity element - it's not necessarily $d^k$, because we might have $k<i$), and we have $d^{i+m} = d^{i+n}$ iff $m\equiv n \pmod k$.